# Do I have to be a super user in order to use the file handling operations of C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the fseek() and ftell() function to find the length of the file 'test.txt' which is present in the same directory as the file 'file.c'.

**file.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int len;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    printf("Error opening file.");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("The size of the file test.txt is: %d.\n", len);

    return 0;  
}
```

**test.txt**

```
abc def
```

There is no problem when I compile the file, but when I try to run it, I'm getting the 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error and the execution terminates.
I'm trying to run this on a standard user in the Ubuntu environment.

Comment: No, you don't need to be a super user. You need permissions for this file.

Comment: if you as a normal user can't open and do things with files then how can you boot the system and log in? How can you run apps including the browser to post this question? Through that process thousands of files have been read/written

Comment: Add a newline to your error printing  like so `printf("Error opening file.\n");` , otherwise the error message might be lost to you. Also, if you cannot open the file, your program should not go further, so exit or return. Your issue is that the program cannot open the file (e.g. you are running the program from another folder than where the file is located, or your program does not have permissions to open that particular file - but even when you fil to open the file, you proceed and call fseek/ftell/fclose on a NULL pointer that causes the segfault.

Comment: How do you compile and run the program?

Comment: The only problem I'm seeing is you are not terminating the program if `fp==NULL`

Comment: Do I need to be a superuser to ask questions on SO?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the error message after putting a \n in the error message. And after that I created a new file ts.text again in the same directory and the code worked. I am not sure why was I getting the error earlier. But it is resolved now.

Comment: Why does your code continue after an error as if there was no error? You are aware this is plain wrong? At the least, terminate the program after an error. Also `ftell` yields a `long`, not an `int`. Use the correct types. Enable warnings, your compiler should complain - pay heed to warnings and fix them.

Comment: `if(fp == NULL)
{ printf("Error opening file."); return 0; }` <-- add this, you need to stop reading from the file if it wasn't opened correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be wondering why you did not see the `printf` statement before the 'Segmentation fault' occurred.

This is due to stream buffering of stdout. You either have `fflush(stdout)` or print a newline `"\n"` to prevent the output from being buffered.
In this case, 'Segmentation fault' has occurred before the buffer is flushed and printed.
So you can try either this:

```
printf("Error opening file.");
fflush(stdout);
```

or this:

```
printf("Error opening file.\n");
```

And of course, do not do anything more with the file pointer if it is NULL.

Actually, you'll better use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) instead of `printf` for such error handling (if you insist on `printf`, show somehow the [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), perhaps as `strerror(errno)`; see also [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)). So we suggest:

```
if(fp == NULL) {
  perror ("fopen test.txt");
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need super user permission here. You are trying to open a file in read only mode. If the file is not existing then `fopen()` fails. Even if the file is not present you are trying to get the length of the file. 
So you can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int len;
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

if(fp == NULL){
printf("Error opening file.\n");
}else{
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
len = ftell(fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("The size of the file test.txt is: %d.\n", len);
}

return 0;
}
```

The problem with your code is probably test.txt is missing on the specified location and you are trying to open it. Even though open fails you are trying to get the length of the file which causes segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open the file to check the length, and doing so increases the risk of failure because of lacking permission, etc.

If you want to check the length of a file (rather than figure out how fseek and ftell are working) I would suggest the following:

```
struct _stat buffer;
if (_stat("test.txt", &buffer) != 0) {
    // stat failed, does file exist? Access?
}
else {
    printf("Length of file %s is %i\n", "test.txt", buffer.st_size);
}
```

Note that I tested the syntax on Windows, and on Ubuntu, you might need to drop the underscore in front of stat.